# Every polynomial that takes square values is another polynomial squared

Tags: polynomials, square-numbers

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $P(n)$ is a perfect square for all integers $n$. Prove or disprove:
There exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $P(x)=Q(x)^2$.